# How to put non-latin text in HTML

Tags: html, fonts, right-to-left

When you have a website in Hebrew ([example](http://www.google.co.il)) is the text that is in hebrew a font or is it a lot of special html characters (such as `&pound;`)?

I am working on a project for a client and his site is in English, Spanish, and French. But his site is about teaching Hebrew. So it needs portions of the site to be in Hebrew. I'm not exactly sure how non-Romance languages work in HTML. It is quite confusing for me. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is a good practise to use images for characters of other languages so that users with custom font set may also see it.

Comment: It is *awful* practise to images for non-latin characters. They take up massive amounts of bandwidth and scale poorly.

Comment: Now imagine someone did that on a site in English (e.g. this question) and someone visited using a screen reader. "Image: W. Image: H. Image: E. Image: N" … and we've only just finished the first word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need authoring tools that are Unicode-enabled and let you produce the document as UTF-8 encoded. If you create pages with an editor, BabelPad is a good choice; see Alan Wood’s [list of tools](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/utilities_editors.html) for alternatives. (It might be a little old, and not all programs listed there are suitable for your use.)

Start the document with

```
<!doctype html>
<html dir=rtl>
<meta charset=utf-8>
```

if the content is dominantly in Hebrew, in which case right-to-left layout is generally to be preferred. Text in English or other left-to-right languages should be wrapped in elements with the attribute `dir=ltr`; individual words, like English names inside a run of Hebrew text, don’t need that, though.

Your authoring tool naturally needs to use some font so that you can see the Hebrew letters, but this need not have anything to do what users will see. If you do not set font, they will see the text in their browser’s default fonts. This is one reason why you should make some font settings in CSS, since the defaults may well mean that e.g. Latin text is displayed in a serif font and Hebrew text in a sans-serif font, and this does not look good. Just make sure that the fonts you list contain Hebrew letters. But you could start with something simple like body { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; } and think about it in more detail later.

You may encounter problems with directionality. Simple Hebrew text and simple English text will normally get rendered properly, Hebrew from right to left and English left to right. But when parentheses, digits, and special characters are involved, problems may arise. Using the `dir` attribute will fix most issues but not all. Recommended reading: [Authoring HTML: Handling Right-to-left Scripts](http://www.w3.org/TR/i18n-html-tech-bidi/).

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. So basically it needs to be in utf-8, set to RTL, and the font needs to support hebrew characters? Do you know where I can find what fonts support hebrew?

Comment: @Dan the Man, check out the list of fonts that support the letter aleph: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/5d0/fontsupport.htm It does not cover all fonts, and some fonts there are not widely in use, but it’s a good starting point. Arial is probably the safest option. (I was bit disappointed at noticing that the so-called C fonts, like Calibri and Cambria, do not contain Hebrew letters.)

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

1. Use an encoding for the HTML that supports the characters you want to use (UTF-8 and UTF-16 are the standard choices, with nothing to choose between them other then a bandwidth saving depending on which characters are used)
2. Use character references for the characters that are not in the encoding you are using

Go with option 1. The W3C have a guide to [handling character encodings in HTML and CSS](http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/tutorial-char-enc/)

Comment: So I use UTF-8 and then what? Do I set a font? Or just start typing Hebrew characters with my keyboard?

Comment: Just start typing Hebrew characters with your keyboard.

Comment: One more question: Would any one else be able to see it no matter what kind of computer they have?

Comment: If they don't have a font that supports the characters, then they won't … but how many people can read Hebrew, will want to look at this site, and won't need such a font for numerous other sites they visit?

Comment: UTF-16 is generally not supported by browsers and is not used on web pages.

Comment: Of course you need a font. Computers can't show any characters without one. There won't be many people wanting to view Hebrew characters who don't have a font that includes them though.